# How to prove $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \min\{s_i,s_j\}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^M c_k^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Let us assume that $s_1,\dots,s_n$ are some given non-negative integers. Let $M=\max\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}$ and for any $k$ let use denote $c_k=|\{i=1,\dots,n; s_i\ge k\}|$. (In the other words, $c_k$ is the number of elements of the given set which have size at least $k$.) Then
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \min\{s_i,s_j\}=\sum_{k=1}^M c_k^2.\tag{*}$$
(Notice that $c_0=n$, however the term $c_0^2$ is not included on the RHS.)

How can we prove this?

This equality seems to be rather elementary (and I have included a proof by induction below). Still, I suppose that there are many interesting ways to prove this, so I thought that it might be reasonable to ask here to see various approaches to this sum and various ways to formulate the arguments why this equality holds.

*Motivation.* This expression appears naturally in some considerations about commuting matrices. See, for example, Robert Israel's answer to [Dimension of a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1023836#1023855). (The sum here is the formula he mentions in the last paragraph, in the case when there is only a single eigenvalue.)

*Example.* Just to make sure that we are not trying to prove something which does not hold, let's have a look at least at one example. (After all, having some examples in front of us might be also useful when thinking about proofs.)

Let us try the numbers $1$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $3$, i.e., $s_1=s_2=1$, $s_3=2$, $s_4=s_5=3$.

We can write down the following table, where we have $\min\{s_i,s_j\}$ in the position $(i,j)$ and the last row/column contain the sums.
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 5 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 5 \\
  1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 8 \\
  1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 &10 \\
  1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 &10 \\\hline
  5 & 5 & 8 &10 &10 &38
\end{array}
$$
At the same time we get $c_1^2+c_2^2+c_3^2=5^2+3^2+2^2=25+9+4=38$.

*A special case.* In particular, if we take $s_i=i$, then we get the sum
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \min\{i,j\}=\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k+1)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6.\tag{⋄}$$
This sum seems to me as a rather natural exercise to give students for manipulation with sums and for trying out combinatorial proofs.

I have tried searching whether there is some question on this site about $(\diamond)$. I did not find such question - the closest one I've seen was this one: [How prove this identity $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}\min{\{i,j\}}(a_{i}-a_{i+1})(b_{j}-b_{j+1})=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2333527)

EDIT: After searching a bit more I found [Combinatorial proof of $\sum_{1\le i\le n,\ 1\le j\le n}\min(i,j)=\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1979770) and [A Combinatorial proof for the identity $\sum_i \sum_j \min(i,j) = \sum_k k^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62167)

*Proof by induction.* There are certainly various more clever proofs, but as a starting point we can try induction on $M$.

$1^\circ$ If $M=0$, then both sides of $(*)$ are equal to zero.

$2^\circ$  Let us assume that the claim is true whenever we have number with maximum less than $M$.

W.l.o.g. we can assume that $s_i\ge1$ for each $i$. (If suffices to notice that by including also $s_i$'s for which $s_i=0$ we add zero to both sides. The RHS is not influenced at all, since such $s_i$'s do not count in $c_k$ for $k\ge1$. On the LHS we are only adding/omiting the terms of the form $\min\{0,s_i\}=0$.)

With this assumption we can use $s'_i=s_i-1$. We can then apply the induction hypothesis on the numbers $s'_i$. By noticing that $\min\{s_i,s_j\}=\min\{s'_i,s'_j\}+1$ and $c_k=c'_{k=1}$ we get
\begin{align*}
S
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \min\{s_i,s_j\} \\
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n (1+\min\{s'_i,s'_j\}) \\
&=n^2+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \min\{s'_i,s'_j\} \\
&=n^2+(c'_1)^2+\dots+(c'_{M-1})^2= \\
&=m^2+c_2^2+\dots+c_M^2= \\
&=c_1^2+c_2^2+\dots+c_M^2
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5):

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $\Pr(X=s_i)=\frac 1n k_i$, where $k_i$ is the number of times where $s_i$ appears in the $n$-uple $\left(s_1,\dots,s_n\right)$. Let $Y$ be an independent copy of $X$. Then 
$$
\frac 1{n^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \min\{s_i,s_j\} = \mathbb E\left[\min\{X,Y\}\right].$$
One the other hand, the latter expectation can be computed by the formula 
$$
\mathbb E\left[Z\right]=\int_0^{+\infty}\Pr(Z\geqslant t)dt, \quad Z\geqslant 0.
$$
With $Z:=\min\{X,Y\}$, we get by independence and the fact that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution that 
$$
\Pr\left(\min\{X,Y\}\geqslant t\right)=\Pr\left(X\geqslant t,Y\geqslant t\right)=\Pr\left(X\geqslant t\right)\Pr\left(Y\geqslant t\right)=\Pr\left(X\geqslant t\right)^2.
$$
Then cutting the integral at integers gives the wanted formula.

Answer (score 2):

One way to show the equality is to show that both sides count the number of the triples
$$\{(i,j,k)\in\mathbb N^3; 1\le i \le n, 1\le j\le n, k\le s_i, 1\le k\le s_j\}.$$

Basically, the difference between the LHS is just the order of sums. We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k\le s_i,s_j} 1
&= \sum_{k=1}^M \sum_{\substack{1\le i\le n \\ s_i\ge k}}
\sum_{\substack{1\le j\le n \\ s_j\ge k}} 1 \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^M \sum_{\substack{1\le i\le n \\ s_i\ge k}} c_k \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^M c_k^2
\end{align*}

Exchanging the order of sums is similar to [Martin R's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3272745/how-to-prove-sum-limits-i-1n-sum-limits-j-1n-min-s-i-s-j-sum-limit/3272897#3272897).

Looking at both sides as counting some triples is perhaps similar to the combinatorial proofs (or picture proofs) posted in the linked questions [A combinatorial proof for the identity $\sum_i \sum_j \min(i,j) = \sum_k k^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62167) and [Combinatorial proof of $\sum_{1\le i\le n,\ 1\le j\le n}\min(i,j)=\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1979770).

Answer (score 2):

Using [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), i.e. $[\cdots]$, define
$$
c_k=\sum_{i=1}^n[s_i\ge k]\tag1
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^Mc_k
&=\sum_{k=1}^M\sum_{i=1}^n[s_i\ge k]\tag{2a}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^M[s_i\ge k]\tag{2b}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^ns_i\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: apply $(1)$
$\text{(2b)}$: change order of summation
$\phantom{a}(2)$: there are $s_i$ values of $k$ for which $s_i\ge k$

Similarly, define
$$
\begin{align}
b_k
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n[\min(s_i,s_j)\ge k]\tag{3a}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n[s_i\ge k][s_j\ge k]\tag{3b}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n[s_i\ge k]\sum_{j=1}^n[s_j\ge k]\tag{3c}\\[6pt]
&=c_k^2\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: definition
$\text{(3b)}$: $\min(s_i,s_j)\ge k\iff s_i\ge k\text{ and }s_j\ge k$
$\text{(3c)}$: rearrange the product
$\phantom{a}(3)$: apply $(1)$

Then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^Mb_k
&=\sum_{k=1}^M\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n[\min(s_i,s_j)\ge k]\tag{4a}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^M[\min(s_i,s_j)\ge k]\tag{4b}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\min(s_i,s_j)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: apply definition $\text{(3a)}$
$\text{(4b)}$: change order of summation
$\phantom{a}(4)$: there are $\min(s_i,s_j)$ values of $k$ for which $\min(s_i,s_j)\ge k$

Equations $(3)$ and $(4)$ say
$$
\sum_{k=1}^Mc_k^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\min(s_i,s_j)\tag5
$$

Comment: Note that $[\cdots]$ are Iverson brackets. $[\text{true}]=1$ and $[\text{false}]=0$, and $[\text{false}]$ even kills $\infty$ and undefined quantities, i.e. $[1=2]/0=0$.

Comment: Nice approach. Two minor corrections: 3b and 3c should both have j instead of i in the second bracket.

Comment: @RobPratt: thanks! Fixed the typos.

Comment: I did not know the Iverson bracket notation, your first identities are what I tried to express using the notation $\Bbb 1_{k \le a_i}$.

Answer (score 1):

We can compute the sum of non-negative integers $a_1, \ldots,a_n$ in terms of their “distribution”:

$$
 \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^\infty \Bbb 1_{k \le a_i}
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^n\Bbb 1_{k \le a_i} =\sum_{k=1}^\infty | \{ i=1,\ldots, n : a_i \ge k \} |
$$

where only finitely many terms are non-zero. In your case
$$
c_k=|\{i=1,\dots,n :  s_i\ge k\}|
$$
implies that
$$
c_k^2=|\{i,j=1,\dots,n :  \min\{s_i,s_j\}\ge k\}|
$$

and therefore
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^n  \min\{s_i,s_j\}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k^2 \, .
$$

Comment: I'll just add that we can also look at $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty | \{ i=1,\ldots, n : a_i \ge k \} |$ as two expressions which are both counting the number of elements of the set $\{(i,k)\in\mathbb N^2; i\le n, k\le a_i\}$.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, that’s what I tried to express formally by summing the indicator function $\Bbb 1_{k \le a_i} $ in two different ways.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks for the bounty! – I decided to spend it on https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3257823/42969 :)